# iPhone: iPhone application testing

Tags: iphone

First, Thanks to all for your quick help for any questions asked in this forum.

I just want to know what are the testing tools coming up with Xcode on Mac as i need to test my iPhone application professionally (or) What do you suggest to use debug and test my application using any (or) built-in tools?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I try is Xcode's "Build and Analyze" menu command.

Next thing is to run Instruments and look for memory and object allocations and disposal.  Instruments should keep you busy for quite a while as it can provide you a wealth of information, including network performance and graphics utilization.

Answer (score 1):

When using instruments, the first method you should check is memory allocation and leaks. When your application leaks, it will spike. Click on this leak and then extend the details to find the exact whereabouts of the leak.

However read the documentation on it all first.

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)